# How to Update Multiple Record in database using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

How do i update the Yes/No Field Select Column using c#? 
Here's my table 1 and table 2:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("update [Table1] set [Select] = @Select, [DocumentName] = @DN where [Table1ID] = " + txtTable1ID.Text + " ", connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox1.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DN", "Form 137");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Parameters.Clear();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox2.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Good Moral");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Parameters.Clear();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox3.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Transcript of Record");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close()
```

The output with this code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
You should never concatenate SQL like this: `[Table1ID] = " + txtTable1ID.Text + " "`.

Instead use parametised SQL, like you've done for other bits, such as the "@Select" parameter.

(Sorry, not enough rep to post this as a comment)

Comment: That does not to answer the question. Please change to a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'd love to, but I don't have enough rep, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a comma:

```
"update [Table1] set [Select] = @Select, [DocumentName] = @DN where [Table1ID] = " + txtTable1ID.Text + ""
```